# href not working after redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following navigation buttons in the main project folder which correctly navigate to each of the pages

**analysis.aspx:**

```
<div id="top-menu" class="float-right">
<ul class="main">
    <li><a href="home.aspx" class="current"><span>Home</span></a> </li>
    <li><a href="analysis.aspx"><span>Analysis</span></a> </li>
    <li><a href="blog.aspx"><span>Blog</span></a> </li>
    <li><a href="contact.aspx"><span>Contact</span></a> </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

When a user logs in correctly, the `analysis.aspx` should redirect to a similar version in say the admin folder

**analysis.aspx.cs:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.User.IsInRole("admin"))
    {
        //Admin
        Response.Redirect("/admin/analysis.aspx");
        //base.OnLoad(e);
    }
    else if (Page.User.IsInRole("member"))
    {
        //Members
    }
    else if (Page.User.IsInRole("trial"))
    {
        //Trial
    }
    Else
    {
        //Keep Out

    }
}
```

This is working fine. However, after the redirect to the admin/analyis.aspx page none of the links work. The page appears to refresh but stays on the same page. I've tried to link to pages in both the base project folder and the admin folder without success, so far I've tried without success. There are 2 home.aspx pages, one in project folder and one in admin.

**admin/analysis.aspx.cs:**

```
<li><a href="home.aspx" class="current"><span>Home</span></a> </li>
<li><a href="~/home.aspx" class="current"><span>Home</span></a> </li>
<li><a href="~/admin/home.aspx" class="current"><span>Home</span></a> </li>
<li><a href="/admin/home.aspx" class="current"><span>Home</span></a> </li>
```

The address bar shows the following after clicking `http://localhost:6246/admin/analysis.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fadmin%2fhome.aspx`

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I guess, `analysis.aspx` page requires authentication which fails and that's why it is occurring.

Comment: I'm redirecting to analysis.apx fine though, I can't navigate back off it?

Comment: sorry, my mistake to understand :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I see your codes it seems you haven't put runat="sever" property on the href. If you want to using ~ as root sign on the asp.net then you need to add runat="server" property, that way will let .NET framework compile the object as an asp.net object.

try this

```
<li><a href="home.aspx" class="current" runat="server"><span>Home</span></a> </li>
<li><a href="~/home.aspx" class="current" runat="server"><span>Home</span></a> </li>
<li><a href="~/admin/home.aspx" class="current" runat="server"><span>Home</span></a> </li>
<li><a href="/admin/home.aspx" class="current" runat="server"><span>Home</span></a> </li>
```

Let me know if it solve your issue

Comment: Yes that's it. runat="server" seems to be the answer to all of my problems. Thank you.